# C# canvas going overpainted

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, line, draw

I have a `Canvas` in my `MainWindow` and I draw a line there. When it draws over the width/height of my `Canvas`, the drawing continues in my `MainWindow`. Is there a mistake in my code or is that normal?

```
<Canvas x:Name="coordinateSystem" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="580" Margin="0,10,283,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1024" Cursor="Cross" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
```

Here is my function I call everytime when I get a new coordinate for my line:

```
// xOld, yOld and t are static
// t represents the time
private void drawPoly(double value) 
{    
    t++;
    Point pOne = new Point(xOld, yOld);
    Point pTwo = new Point(t, value);

    GeometryGroup lineGroup = new GeometryGroup();
    LineGeometry connectorGeometry = new LineGeometry();
    connectorGeometry.StartPoint = pOne;
    connectorGeometry.EndPoint = pTwo;
    lineGroup.Children.Add(connectorGeometry);
    System.Windows.Shapes.Path path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
    path.Data = lineGroup;
    path.StrokeThickness = 1;
    path.Stroke = path.Fill = Brushes.Red;

    coordinateSystem.Children.Add(path);    

    xOld = t;
    yOld = value;
}
```

thx

`PS:` Is there a way to save all drawn points? I want later resize my canvas (zoom out/zoom in) or if the time going to big move my painted line in my canvas and then I need to draw all points again.

Answer (score 2):

Canvases do not clip child elements. If you want to stop the child elements from being drawn outside of the Canvas, you'll need to set ClipToBounds to true or set the Clip of the Canvas.